# Hide data labels of a Highcharts Pie chart using Swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

I am creating Pie chart using Highcharts library in iOS-Swift 5.0

I don't want data labels. Only wants legends at bottom. So I tried to hide it by using below code.

```swift
let plotoptions = HIPlotOptions()  //Line 1
plotoptions.pie = HIPie()         //Line 2
plotoptions.pie.allowPointSelect =  NSNumber(value: true) //Line 3
plotoptions.pie.cursor = "pointer"  //Line 4
plotoptions.pie.dataLabels = HIDataLabels()   //Line 5
plotoptions.pie.dataLabels.enabled = NSNumber(value: false) //Line 6
plotoptions.pie.showInLegend = true  //Line 7
```

But I am getting these errors:

> Cannot assign value of type 'HIDataLabels' to type '[HIDataLabelsOptionsObject]?'  at line number 5

> Value of type '[HIDataLabelsOptionsObject]?' has no member 'enabled' at line number 6

I used this [demo](https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/pie-legend) written in Objective-C as an example.

Comment: See this issue from `highcharts-ios` github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios/issues/202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: There were some changes in the latest HICharts API (8.0.0) that remove HIDataLabelsOptionsObject(), see updated answer in code below.

Here is how I got this to work.  It turns out you don't need the allowPointSelect, cursor, or showInLegend flags (though you would probably want to keep the showInLegend flag, because you want a legend on your chart) to get this to work.  I don't really know what allowPointSelect or cursor do, because you can still tap on the chart and see the details.

```
plotoptions.pie = HIPie()
let dataLabel = HIDataLabels() // Older versions of API - HIDataLabelsOptionsObject()
dataLabel.enabled = false
plotoptions.pie.dataLabels = [dataLabel]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's correct and this what I expect. @D. Pratt